# Knockout.js: How to display loading image at completion of asynchronous call

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I need to display a loading gif while a background task (using JQuery promises is executed). I have most    of the code however my problem is the following:

**Problem**: the loading gif is displayed when the data is ready to be displayed, which defeats the purpose of using a loading gif! How do I display the gif right at the start and then remove it after the data is ready to be displayed.

I'm using a KO's custom binding handler with an observable flag.

You can see the code in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zL8vtwsa/2/)

**JavaScript:**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.loadingList = {

    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if (valueAccessor() == true) {
            $(element).wrap($('<div>', {
                "class": "loading"
            }));
            $(element).before($('<div>', {
                "class": "loading_inner"
            }));
        } else {
            $(element).parent().replaceWith($(element));
        }
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if (valueAccessor() == true) {
            $(element).wrap($('<div>', {
                "class": "loading"
            }));
            $(element).before($('<div>', {
                "class": "loading_inner"
            }));
        } else {
            $(element).parent().replaceWith($(element));
        }
    }
};


function PersonViewModel(callback) {
    var self = this;

    self.InProgress = ko.observable(true);
    self.persons = ko.observableArray([]);

    // Get available audits

    var promises = [];
    promises.push(GetPersons());

    $.when.apply($, promises).then(function () {
        self.persons(arguments[0]);
        self.InProgress(false);
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new PersonViewModel());

function GetPersons() {

    var dfrd = $.Deferred();

    var result = [{
        Name: 'John Smith',
        Country: 'USA'
    }, {
        Name: 'Juan Carlos',
        Country: 'Spain'
    }];

    setTimeout(function () {
        dfrd.resolve(result)
    }, 3000);

    return dfrd;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
     <h1>Persons</h1>

    <hr />
    <table data-bind="foreach: persons, loadingList:InProgress()">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><span>Name</span>

                </th>
                <th><span>Country</span>

                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><span data-bind="text:Name"></span>

                </td>
                <td><span data-bind="text:Country"></span>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <td>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just edited your update code with this

```
 setTimeout( function(){$(element).parent().parent().replaceWith($(element));}, 1000);
```

Set time out was just to check whether loading was appearing
http://jsfiddle.net/zL8vtwsa/30/

As per your comments, I tried it around with a container less binding for display and I think this will serve the purpose

http://jsfiddle.net/zL8vtwsa/78/

```
  <tbody>
             <!-- ko  foreach:persons -->
             <!-- /ko -->
  </tbody>
```

Comment: Thank you Rohith Nair for your help. I'm giving you an up vote. How do I show the loading gif at the start? As I mentioned in my post the gif is being displayed just as data ready to be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

The code in your update method replaces the parent div (.loading) but doesn't remove the element before it (.loading-inner) <s>which by the way is inserted outside of the .loading div</s>.

```
else {
    $(element).parent().replaceWith($(element));
}
```

So it would seem the loading spinner is just being added to the wrong place, <s>I've fixed it by using `.prepend` rather then `.before`, see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/2x6wx6wa/2/</s>

some other bits. the `GetPersons` function should return `return dfrd.promise()` to make it immutable, Create/Update are both applied when this code is first run, check in your update method if the loading spinner has already been appended.

**Edit:**

The loading spinner isn't shown at the start because of the following CSS, when removed it works fine:

```
.loading {
    display: table;
    position: relative;
}
```

Instead of using prepend/before, I've added a check to ensure the loading div is only added once which turned out to be the "real" underlying issue on closer inspection. See changes here: http://jsfiddle.net/tkvvjutx/

Comment: Thank you Dead.Rabit. I checked your code and two things: first, the loading gif doesn't show at the start but only shows with the data. Second, the gif is not being removed after the data is replaced.